# When saving team information, I get an error, but the information is saved

Tags: bug, status-completed, old-teams

Well, exactly what the title says.

I changed the description of [my team](https://stackoverflow.com/teams/116/coolblue) and clicked 'Save'. I got a message saying *"Oops! Something Bad Happened!"* and a nice apology stating that it wasn't my fault.

I tried a couple of times but kept getting the error. I also get the error if I save right away without changing a thing.

But when going back to the team page, it turned out the change was applied after all, so no harm done. But still I though I should mention it.

Comment: Is anything else loading on the page when you hit Save? I haven't used Teams at all but I know that Voting and Commenting will flash an error message if you navigate off the page right after doing it.

Comment: Nope. I go to the team page, wait a couple of second to be sure (no loading indicator and nothing going on the page), click the 'Edit Contents & Settings' link and wait again, and then I click 'Save Edits', which immediately takes me to that error page.

Comment: @GolezTrol Thanks for letting us know. We'll look into the issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Whoops - I let a `NullReferenceException` to creep into that.

All fixed and deployed now.

Comment: Confirmed. It works now. No error if I save, regardless of making changes or not. And, not unimportantly, if I *do* make a change, it is still actually saved. :)